# How to Access Auth Token in Unity with GameCenter Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, game-center

I would like to add the GameCenter Authentication with Firebase to my Unity Game. But in the documentation there isn't the GameCenter part (only Play Games one).
I already achieved the "Unity part":

```
public static void GameCenterAuth()
    {
        GameCenterPlatform.ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner(true);
        Social.localUser.Authenticate (GameCenterProcessAuth);
    }

    static void GameCenterProcessAuth(bool success)
    {
        if (success) 
        {
            Social.ReportProgress("Achievement01", 100, (result) => {
            Debug.Log(result ? "Reported achievement" : "Failed to report achievement");
        });

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("Failed to authenticate");
        }
    }
```

But it misses the link with Firebase. For this I need to get the access token of GameCenter but like the doc doesn't exist, I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully there aren't many holes in the Unity documentation, but when you do find one you can often find sample code in the [Unity Quickstarts](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity) (as these are also used to validate changes to the Unity SDK).

From [`UIHandler.cs`](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/auth/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Auth/UIHandler.cs) in the [Auth quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/auth/testapp):

```
    public Task SignInWithGameCenterAsync() {
      var credentialTask = Firebase.Auth.GameCenterAuthProvider.GetCredentialAsync();
      var continueTask = credentialTask.ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        if(!task.IsCompleted)
          return null;

        if(task.Exception != null)
          Debug.Log("GC Credential Task - Exception: " + task.Exception.Message);

        var credential = task.Result;

        var loginTask = auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
        return loginTask.ContinueWithOnMainThread(HandleSignInWithUser);
      });

      return continueTask;
    }
```

What's weird about GameCenter is that you don't manage the credential directly, rather you [request it from GameCenter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/game-center-auth-provider#getcredentialasync) ([Here's PlayGames](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/play-games-auth-provider#getcredential) by comparison, which you have to [cache the result of `Authenticate` manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/play-games#authenticate_with_firebase)).

So in your code, I'd go into the `if (success)` block and add:

```
GameCenterAuthProvider.GetCredentialAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    // I used ContinueWith
    // be careful, I'm on a background thread here.
    // If this is a problem, use ContinueWithOnMainThread
    if (task.Exception != null) {
        FirebaseAuth.GetInstance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(task.Result).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            // I used ContinueWithOnMainThread
            // You're on the Unity main thread here, so you can add or change scene objects
            // If you're comfortable with threading, you can change this to ContinueWith
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/game-center This might answer your question. You may have to implement this feature in XCode when you export the project from unity

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I saw this part but I am looking for the way  to make it directly in Unity. I think it’s possible because following this link there is a class with the GetCredentialAsync method that allow you to Auth with firebase. But the method take a token auth in argument and I don’t know how to get it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/game-center-auth-provider

Answer (score 0):

To complete Patrick's answer I found the machahamster GitHub repo where they use the Game Center Auth with Firebase on Unity.
If it can helps someone:
https://github.com/google/mechahamster/blob/b5ab9762cc95a2a36156d0cbd1dc08fb767c4080/Assets/Hamster/Scripts/Menus/GameCenterSignIn.cs#L45